# Laravel orWhereHas returning php fatal error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, fatal-error

This is strange.

On my development machine (vagrant w/ Debian Wheezy, PHP 5.5.7), the following eloquent query works as expected:

```
Company::whereUserId($user_id)->orWhereHas('users', function($q) use ($user_id) {

    $q->where('users.id', '=', $user_id);
});
```

My 'Company' model defines the relationship:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'company_user', 'company_id', 'user_id');
    }
```

However, on production, same OS and PHP version I am getting a FATAL PHP error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getQuery() on a non-object
> in
> /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php
> on line 247

I am stumped. I have tried just `->has('users)`, which works so I know the foreign model is being used. But it is so strange that I am getting different results per environment! Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the specs on your production OS/PHP?

Comment: PHP Version => 5.4.4-14+deb7u7 && Debian 3.2.51-1 x86_64

Comment: I ended up upgrading to php 5.5.7 and it seems to have resolved. Not sure why.